How can I make an already rigged model be controlled by newly added bones?
I learned a physical method that requires multiple types of bones. So, I need add some bones. But the new bones can not control the model.

hello your question is too vague, maybe add details, maybe a screenshot, etc

A bone controls some vertices of the mesh if theese conditions are set:

The mesh has an Armature modifier, targeting the Armature that contains the bone.

The vertices are part of a vertex group which has the same exact name of the bone.


Every vertex can be assigned to more than a single vertex group, so it can be controlled by more than one bone: weights values are used to distribute and control the influence between bones/vertex groups.
So you can add new bones to an existing armature, then create on the mesh some new vertex groups with the same name of the bones, and assign them some vertices with a weight (in edit mode) or via weight painting.
Or adding new bones with a new armature: a similar method, but needs an additional Armature modifier, targeting the new armature object (generally worse, unless necessary).
Usually the mesh is parented to the Armaturo object in object mode, but this isn't strictly necessary.
